# Why single quotes inside .php file are encoded?

Tags: javascript, php, html

somefile.php

```
<?php
//some php code
?>

<script>
      MyObject.someVar = 'some_text';
</script>
```

This file results single quotes in JavaScript to be encoded:

```
<script>
     MyObject.someVar = &#039;some_text&#039;;
</script>
```

But if double quotes were used everything will be okay. What may be the problem with single quotes?

Comment: I've never seen that happen.

Comment: Is this your actual script, or does the real script use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: Are you getting the text from a database? Does the code that writes to the DB sanitize it with `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: It is not the exact sctript. I tried to mimic it. Mentioned functions are not applied. The same code work fine for others but failes for a single costumer.

Comment: No it is not from database. It is hardcoded.

Comment: If it's only failing for a single customer, I suspect they have a browser extension that's doing it.

Comment: It happens with my browser also.

Comment: My guess is it's something that's intended to protect against XSS.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Do you see the entity if you use `View Source`? What if you look at the raw response in the Network tab of DevTools?

Comment: I see a JavaScript error. Then look at sources and see the encoded quotes.

Comment: This file is loaded with ajax. May it be the cause?

Comment: Are you assigning to `innerText` or `innerHTML`? `innerText` will convert special characters to entities.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your efforts. The problem was related decoding htmlspecialchars() applied string in JavaScript.